# How to add a file type to WinEdt's Open File

Tags: winedt

In WinEdt <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> brings a window to select a file that user wants to open. One can select which file types will be displayed; for example TeX, HTML and many others. In TeX category there are several different file types listed.

Two questions:

Is it possible to change this, or add a new category, so that only TeX files are displayed?

How to change the default so that TeX category appears whenever <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> is used?

I use WinEdt 9 Build: 20140917

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File types that are shown in the Open dialog depend on the "modes" defined in `Modes.ini`.

This is what you have to do.

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. In the "Options Interface", double-click the "Modes" item (`Modes.ini` gets opened).

   You will see the following modes listed

   ```
   MODE="Default|*.*"
   MODE="TeX|*.tex;*.ltx;*.texi;*.dtx;*.fdd;*.drv;*.ins;*.sty;*.fd;*.def;"+
            "*.clo;*.cls;*.aux;*.lof;*.lot;*.toc;*.bbl;*.gls;*.glo;*.ind;*.idx"
   MODE="BibTeX|*.bib"
   MODE="MetaFont|*.mf"
   MODE="MetaPost|*.mp;*.mpx"
   MODE="BST|*.bst"
   MODE="IST|*.ist"
   MODE="HTML|*.html;*.htm;*.shtml;*.shtm;*.php;*.hhc;*.hhk"
   MODE="NSIS|*.nsi;*.nsh"
   MODE="DATA|*.*;*.dat;*.ini;*.cfg;*.dic"
   MODE="ASCII|*.*;*.txt;*.edt"
   MODE="ANSI|*.*;*.doc"
   MODE="Fortran|*.for;*.f;*.f77;*.f90;*.f95"
   MODE="Binary|*.*;*.exe;*.dll;*.com;*.dvi;*.bmp"
   MODE="Application|*.exe;*.com;*.bat"
   ```

   As you can see, the "Default" mode containing all file types is listed as first.
3. So, if you want the "TeX" mode to be the default simply switch the lines

   ```
   MODE="Default|*.*"
   ```

   and

   ```
   MODE="TeX|*.tex;*.ltx;*.texi;*.dtx;*.fdd;*.drv;*.ins;*.sty;*.fd;*.def;"+
            "*.clo;*.cls;*.aux;*.lof;*.lot;*.toc;*.bbl;*.gls;*.glo;*.ind;*.idx"
   ```

   In this way, when you press <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd>, you will see all those file types (`.tex`, `.ltx`, etc.).

   If instead, you want to see *only* `.tex` files, leave those lines as they are, and before the line

   ```
   MODE="Default|*.*"
   ```

   add

   ```
   MODE="TeX|*.tex"
   ```
4. At this point, press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file and you're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear, well written answer.